# Roslyn scripting: Line number information for run time exceptions

Tags: c#, debugging, scripting, roslyn

I am messing around with the Roslyn scripting stuff (using the `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting` nuget package), and I wonder if there is a way to add line number information to the stack traces for exceptions that happen inside a script.

When I run the following C# code:

```
// using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;

var code = @"
var a = 0;
var b = 1 / a;
";
try
{
    await CSharpScript.RunAsync(code);
}
catch (DivideByZeroException dbze)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dbze.StackTrace);
}
```

The stack trace written to the console is:

```
   at Submission#0.<<Initialize>>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.ScriptExecutionState.<RunSubmissionsAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.Script`1.<RunSubmissionsAsync>d__21.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at UnitTests.ExploreRoslyn.<ScriptWithRuntimeError>d__4.MoveNext() in D:\dev\misc\netmockery\UnitTests\ExploreRoslyn.cs:line 47
```

Note that if I try to catch the exception inside the script, the result is similar:

```
var code = @"
try  {
    var a = 0;
    var b = 1 / a;
}
catch (System.DivideByZeroException dbze)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dbze.StackTrace);
}
";
await CSharpScript.RunAsync(code);
```

This outputs:

```
at Submission#0.<<Initialize>>d__0.MoveNext()
```

To the console.

Is there a way to make the Roslyn scripting engine add debug information when compiling/executing the script, so I can get line number information in the stack trace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got something working by emitting an (in-memory) assembly with debug information.

Example code:

```
var code = @"
var a = 0;
var b = 1 / a;
";

var script = CSharpScript.Create(code);
var compilation = script.GetCompilation();
var ilstream = new MemoryStream();
var pdbstream = new MemoryStream();
compilation.Emit(ilstream, pdbstream);

var assembly = Assembly.Load(ilstream.GetBuffer(), pdbstream.GetBuffer());
var type = assembly.GetType("Submission#0");
var factory = type.GetMethod("<Factory>");
var submissionArray = new object[2];
Task<object> task = (Task<object>)factory.Invoke(null, new object[] { submissionArray });

try
{
    await task;
}
catch (DivideByZeroException dbze)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dbze.StackTrace);
}
```

The output is (notice the `:line 3` in the stack trace):

```
   at Submission#0.<<Initialize>>d__0.MoveNext() in :line 3
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at UnitTests.ExploreRoslyn.<ExploreEmittingAssembly>d__13.MoveNext() in D:\dev\misc\netmockery\UnitTests\ExploreRoslyn.cs:line 151
```

Now obviously this is a bit of a hack, and I'm not really happy with the hardcoded script engine implementation details (`Submission#0`, `<Factory>`), plus I don't really know what I'm doing. There should be (and maybe there is?) a better way.

### Update

Created issue https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/13482 in the Roslyn issue tracker.

Comment: You can use `compilation.GetEntryPoint()` to obtain the factory method's symbol. Then you can use `entryPoint.ContainingType.MetadataName` to get the submission's class name and `entryPoint.Name` to get the factory method's name. It will feel less hacky :-)

Comment: Note that `compilation.GetEntryPoint()` requires a _cancellation token_, so just pass `CancellationToken.None` to the method...

Comment: If you load the assembly like this, will it forever be in the process' memory? I thought this wouldn't be the case for the regular script execution API. Or at least it wouldn't load another assembly each time the script is executed. But I'm not sure about that. Anyway, that GitHub issue is now closed but there's no solution yet.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I believe that there is no way to unload an assembly from a .NET process (except for creating a separate AppDomain and unloading the entire AppDomain).

Comment: TLDR; With the latest versions you can enable line numbers via this call => 'ScriptOptions.Default.WithEmitDebugInformation(true)'