# Roslyn/CSharpScript - How to Save/Load Compilation to avoid compilation wait time

Tags: c#, scripting, roslyn

I'm trying to integrate c# scripting into my database application. I'm using the *globals* object to make global variables accessible from the script.

I'm not happy with the wait time if the script is compiled for the first time.
How can I save and load the compilation to avoid the wait time?

```
Script<object> script = CSharpScript.Create(scriptCode, globalsType: typeof(MyGlobals));
script.Compile();   //<-- load the Compilation from database/file here
script.RunAsync(myGlobalsInstance).Wait();
```

Comment: You should probably compile a normal assembly instead of a script.

Comment: info on how to create the compilation manually is [here](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting/CSharpScriptCompiler.cs,49)

Answer (score 4):

You can create a CSharpScript, then get the compilation via `GetCompilation` to get the compilation.

```
var script = CSharpScript.Create("script..");
var compilation = script.GetCompilation();
```

From the compilation, you can actually `compilation.Emit()` the dll and pdb to disk or memory. The tricky (and roslyn internal bit) is how to get the delegate of the code to execute, once you have the assembly. You can see how roslyn does it [here](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting/Script.cs,dd0708fa09c9ef76).

Comment: Ok, so i can emit the assembly to stream. But if I understand aright, there is no (simple) way to load the Compilation data back to a CSharpScript?

Comment: why would you need the CSharpScript if you have the assembly (.dll)? You load that up (Assembly.Load), create the type (Activator.CreateType), and create the delegate to be executed.

Comment: AFAIK a c# script does not have an entry point and, in my case, it should have directly access to the members of the "globals" variable. That is, what i want to re-load from stream and i have no idea how to do this.

Comment: When you have the assembly on disk/memory, you can execute the script like suggested in the 2nd part of @SegeyL's answer

Comment: A c# script does not have any class to instanciate an there is no method to execute - that's my problem.

Comment: @Bogomil can you please provide an example script, so we know what you're talking about?

Comment: I have found a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39243866/roslyn-scripting-line-number-information-for-run-time-exceptions).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to pre-compile you can use classes from System.CodeDom.Compiler;

```
CompilerParameters opts = new CompilerParameters();

opts.OutputAssembly = <Destination FileName>;
opts.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(<needed references>);
//set other options;            

var codeProvider = new Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider();
var results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(opts, <Your script source files>);
//check that there's no errors in the results.Errors
```

Now you have a complied assembly on the disk. You can load it dynamically, instantiate a class from it and execute methods. You should design the code that you run in the script that it accept some configuration. You should take these steps:

```
var mydll =  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(<compiled Assembly From the previous step>);
    var classInstance =  <YouTypeOrInterface>mydll.CreateInstance(
      <TypeFromTheAssembly>, 
      false, 
      BindingFlags.CreateInstance, 
      null,                                                                
      new object[] { <Arguments you need to provides to your class constructor> },                                                                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, null);
```

Now you can do what you want with this instance. E.g. classInstance.ExecuteSomething(...)

Comment: Note that C# script is different than normal C#, so trying to compile the scripts with CodeDOM probably won't work and would require changing the scripts. Also, if you're doing this, I don't see any reason to use CodeDOM instead of Roslyn, which can also compile assemblies.